# Message box won't display

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

I want a message box to appear if the email/ password is incorrect when logging in. However nothing happens with this else statement. Does it need to be placed somewhere else for it to work?

```
MyConn = New OleDbConnection 
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString 
    MyConn.Open() 

    str1 = ("SELECT * FROM [UserData] WHERE [Username] = '" & TxtUserName.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & TxtPassword.Text & "'") 
    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, MyConn)
    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader 
    While dr.Read() 
        userFound = True 
        TxtPassword.Text = dr("Username").ToString 
        TxtUserName.Text = dr("Password").ToString 
        FirstNameToPass = dr("First Name").ToString 
        LastNameToPass = dr("Last Name").ToString 
        AddressToPass = dr("Address").ToString 
        EmailToPass = dr("Email").ToString 
        If userFound = True Then
            UserAccountView.Show() 
            Me.Hide() 
            TxtPassword.Clear() 
            TxtUserName.Clear() 
        Else
            MsgBox("Login is incorrect")
        End If
    End While
    MyConn.Close() 
End If
```

Comment: dr.Read() will always return something even if no result found since it's a reader. Just do a first request with SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [UserData] WHERE [Username] = '" & TxtUserName.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & TxtPassword.Text & "'") if the result is zero then "Login is incorrect"

Comment: @Plutonix should i answer on the duplicate then?

Comment: Side notes: Dont ask the same question over and over (within hours); always use SQL parameters and never store passwords as plain text

Comment: What @Plutonix said. I even said this is my answer on your other question. Please please use parameters at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use a `Count()` to check if user exists and correct.

**Note:**

- In NoAlias's answer it doesn't solve the problem that userFound will always be true.

So I implemented this solution there might be few errors since i'm not familiar with OleDb but nothing to big hopefully

I also implemented the `Using` as it is good practice to implement it when working with: `IDisposable()`

```
Using MyConn As New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    MyConn.Open()
    Dim check As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [UserData] WHERE [Username] = '" & TxtUserName.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & TxtPassword.Text & "'"
    Dim UserExist As Boolean = False
    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(check, MyConn)
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            If reader(0) = 0 Then
                UserExist = False
            Else
                UserExist = True
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    If UserExist = True Then
        Dim getData As String = "SELECT * FROM [UserData] WHERE [Username] = '" & TxtUserName.Text & "'"
        Dim command2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(getData, MyConn)
        Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command2.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                userFound = True
                TxtPassword.Text = dr("Username").ToString
                TxtUserName.Text = dr("Password").ToString
                FirstNameToPass = dr("First Name").ToString
                LastNameToPass = dr("Last Name").ToString
                AddressToPass = dr("Address").ToString
                EmailToPass = dr("Email").ToString
            End While
        End Using
    Else
        MsgBox("Login is incorrect")
    End If
    MyConn.Close()
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL returns no results, which will be the case when the credentials are wrong, the MessageBox code will never be called.  Put this code block after your While statement.

```
If userFound = True Then
    UserAccountView.Show() 
    Me.Hide() 
    TxtPassword.Clear() 
    TxtUserName.Clear() 
Else
    MsgBox("Login is incorrect")
End If
```

Comment: This still won't be a proper solution since userFound will always be true